# Export a project referenced as a library on a web project to tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a project which reference another project (like this example : http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/EDT_Tutorial_edt_richui_sql02_service_project_Java_build_path.JPG) and when I run my dynamic web project i got the NoClassDefFoundError.

I checked the checkbox on the Order & Export tab.

I succeeded when I created a jar of that project and placed it in WEB-INF/lib but I don't want to rebuild manually that jar everytime, how to do that ?

PS : I'm not using maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up where the projects in your Java Build Path should end up in the deployment.  Yes, this is something for which you can use Maven.  In your case, I think you should be going to the EGL Development Deployment page.  If this were a conventional DWP, I'd say to use the Deployment Assembly (http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.2.0/NewAndNoteworthy/javaee.php) page.

Comment: I used the deployment assembly page and added my project to it and it worked, thanks a lot !